# MATLAB - Using mat2cell to divide a MxN matrix into 1xM cell with different sizes within

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, cell, cell-array

This is the problem:

I have a matrix with `MxN` size and I want divide it into a cell of size `1xM`, but each row `M` of the cell contains an array of size `1xNi` (this means the arrays have different size).

I am trying to do this using mat2cell function but I want to avoid using loops and I don't know how to do it.

I will try to explain my problem with an example. Suppose that I have a matrix

```
X = [1,4,6,9; 2,3,6,7; 5,9,8,7; 9,8,7,10]
```

What I want the code to do is take the values `X<=6` of each row and put them in a `1xM` cell. So the answer should be:

```
ans =


C{1} = [1,4,6]
C{2} = [2,3,6]
C{3} = [5]
C{4} = []
```

So far I have created a loop which goes through all rows of the matrix to find the elements that meet the condition:

```
for i = 1:Mrows
    C{i} = X(i,X(i,:)<=6,:);
end
```

This gives me the result I want but it takes too much time specially when the size of the matrix is very big.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `num2cell(A,2)` to convert each row into a cell and then apply `cellfun` to remove values smaller than 6:

```
X = [1,4,6,9; 2,3,6,7; 5,9,8,7; 9,8,7,10];
C = num2cell(X,2);
res = cellfun(@(x) x(x<=6),C,'UniformOutput',0);
```

and you get:

```
{
 [1,4,6];
 [2,3,6];
 [5];
 []
}
```

Comment: I tried it and it works perfect! And simpler than what I had written! Thanks :).

Answer (score 0):

You might consider preallocating memory, i.e., creating an empty `C` cell array before you start to fill it:

```
X = [1,4,6,9; 2,3,6,7; 5,9,8,7; 9,8,7,10];
Mrows = numel(X(:,1));

C = cell(Mrows,1); %preallocate memory

for i = 1:Mrows
    C{i} = X(i,X(i,:)<=6,:);
end
```